# Can I receive a UAE transit visa after entering the country on a tourist visa within the last 30 days?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, uae, emirates

I hold an Indian passport.

I have an upcoming trip spanning 38 days with the following itinerary on an Emirates ticket:

US -> Dubai -> US

Now, after staying in Dubai for 3 weeks, I'm planning to add a trip to India in between on a non-Emirates ticket. I need to come back to Dubai to catch my flight back to the US:

Dubai -> India -> Dubai

I'll need to go through passport control and enter Dubai again a second time. This is to get my boarding pass and also collect my baggage and re-check to the Emirates flight to the US.

For the first entry into Dubai, I can use the pre-arranged 30/90 day visa from Emirates. For the second entry into Dubai, I was hoping that I could apply for a 96-hour transit visa.

Now, I know that there is a requirement of a gap of 30 days after exiting Dubai before re-applying for a new visa. My question is whether this applies if the "new visa" is a transit visa?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First check with emirates or use their website, if they are able to issue 96 hour visa. Remember 96 hour visa is only issued if your outward journey is from dubai to US or vice versa. Your travel plan is bit complicated, only they will be able to advise!!

Answer (score 2):

The rule you are talking about applies to the normal short stay visas; and it there to prevent people from working/residing in Dubai without a proper work or permanent resident visa.

You can apply for your transit visa in advance (it takes 3-4 days to process) [here](http://www.dubaivisa.net/online/duration96hours.html).